# SQL - Return only records that have duplicate values in a specific column of a left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  inv.name,
  loc.city,
  cls.color
FROM INVENTORY inv
INNER JOIN Model mod ON mod.id = inv.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location loc ON loc.id = mod.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Class cls ON cls.id = mod.id
ORDER BY name, city asc;
```

Which will give me the following...

```
   NAME    | CITY      | Color
1  Bob       New York    Red
2  Janet     Denver      Green
3  John      New York    Blue
```

But my desired results are...

```
   NAME    | CITY      | Color
1  Bob       New York    Red
2  John      New York    Blue
```

There are several posts that are similar but do not seem to work for my specific query since I am joining multiple tables using an inner join and two left outer joins. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to explain the logic behind your expected output. Are you selecting only male names? Cities on the East Coast?

Comment: Can you better explain the logic?  Duplicates of what and where?  Also, I removed the sql-server tag, because the preponderance of evidences suggests Oracle.

Comment: My apologize. I'm looking to return rows that have any duplicate values in the City column. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why are you selecting DISTINCT - is it possible to have duplicate rows (which means they have the same name AND the same city AND the same color)? If that is not possible than a simple SELECT suffices. Then: if duplicates ARE possible, do you want those rows to count as "duplicate" for the city, or do you need to find the city at least twice, with different NAME or different COLOR?

Comment: I am using DISTINCT because my actual query is more complex and I was simplifying it but trying to keep the main structure. Any record may have duplicate values in any column but I am only interested in records that have duplicates in the CITY column. If the entire row is a duplicate, as long as the value in the CITY Column is a duplicate I want to include it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want cities that appear more than once, use analytic functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here without the order by>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by city) as city_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where city_cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Or add the analytic `count()` to the original query, no need to add it in a separate subquery.

Comment: @mathguy I knew I needed to use count() but I am not sure the best way to use it within my original query.

Comment: It depends on what you are really trying to do, and your data; I just asked a couple of questions in a Comment to your original post.